# how to manage google user(gmail) session using sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, google-signin

I am developing android app. In my app i provided login with google functionality. If i use following code in same activity then it works well for logout from google.-

```
if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(googleApiClient);
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
            googleApiClient.connect();
}
```

**Question -**

How to manage google user session using SharedPreferences?
or How to initialize googleApiClient object in SessionManager class?

Thanks.

Comment: @Niranjan..Have you found any solution for this issue..